# Математические операции в запросе sql php

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

Такой вопрос можно ли проводить прстейшие арифметические операции в запросе SQL UPDATE например у меня есть в таблице поле id и count и есть переменная $set в которой записанно число, и что бы мне увеличить в базе данных в конкретной строке значение count прибавив к нему данные из переменной $set мне сначало надо через SELECT сделать выборку нужнйо стркои и записав в переменную уже произвести сложение с данными count а только потом уже сделать UPDATE и записать результат. Можно ли сделать такое простое действие каким то одним запросом?? например что то вроде того:

```
 $set = 100;

  $add = $db->stmt_init();
    $add->prepare("UPDATE mintable SET count= (count + ".$set.") WHERE id='11'");
    $add = $add->execute();
```

Comment: да :). `"UPDATE mintable SET count = count + ".$set." WHERE id='11'"` должен работать.

Comment: Можно, могли бы сперва проверить :<

Comment: Поле count везде в запросах обрамляйте `косыми` апострофами. Это зарезервированное слово SQL

Comment: @exvayn пробую вот так $add->prepare("UPDATE mintable SET cou = cou + '".$set."' WHERE id=?");
  $add->bind_param('i',$id']); потому что мне иногда id надо подставлять - не работает(( выдает в бинд парам invalid object or resurse кажется что то не правильно со сложением - если убрать его то все проходит

Comment: Ясно,  что не так со сложением - слагаемое в апострофах.

Comment: @dantelol вставляйте в запрос `$set` как _число_, а не как _строку_.

Comment: @exvayn так через бинд?? $add->prepare("UPDATE mintable SET cou = cou + ? WHERE id=?");
  $add->bind_param('ii',$set,$id); тоже не работает((

Comment: мб вы хотели написать: `$query = $add->prepare("UPDATE mintable SET cou = cou + ? WHERE id=?");` и `$query->bind_param('ii',$set,$id);`

Comment: @exvayn да почти просто я не пишу там до этого идет еще $add = $db->stmt_init(); по сути если убрать cou + из запроса то все сработает но вот с этим почему то ощибка все таки наверно чего то не хватает может скобок каких то?

Comment: Абсолютно идентичный код у меня локально проходит. Ошибка не в синтаксисе. Может $set или $id отсутствует. Может тип поля нечисловое. 

Comment: @exvayn уффф вот так заработало когда скобки подставил $add->prepare("UPDATE mintable SET cou = (cou + ?) WHERE id=?");
  $add->bind_param('ii',$set,$id); Спасибо за помощь)